# iCloud container create unique filenames

Tags: objective-c, icloud

Is it possible to ensure that all files created in iCloud container have unique filenames? I can imagine that with many devices running I will eventually stumble upon the files created with the same name on a number of devices.

Certainly the easiest solution would be to prepend all filenames with hour/minute/second, but I'd like to maintain a nice file structure where files in conflict would be renamed with version #.

In my case I organize file storage by month and year and so within each months file are named as File 1, File 2, File 3... File n.

Comment: Have you considered postpending a UUID?

Comment: @JanGreve sure but isn't it ugly? I am thinking if I could use unique filenames and then somehow set up NSMetadataItemDisplayNameKey to be more user friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that iCloud automatically renames files created with the same name on different devices. iCloud numbers files if it spots the digit at the end of file name, e.g. if file `File - 1337.jpg` was created twice on different devices, then after sync one file or another will be renamed to `File -1338.jpg` automatically.